# How frequently are airplane windows cleaned?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, windows, cleaning

When you’re driving on the highway, after sometime unwanted insects and dirt accumulate on your windshield. When you stop over at a gas station, you might clean it off. It’s likely the case for aircraft as well, especially during takeoff and landing. **But how frequently are airplane windshields cleaned**? And how are they cleaned? Does this include cleaning of passenger windows?

Comment: Are you interested specifically in commercial operations, or are you wondering about GA as well?

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25881/do-airlines-ever-clean-their-planes

Comment: @RonBeyer commercial, but now I’m wondering about GA too

Comment: for GA airplanes you are supposed to clean the windows before every flight. This is part of the checklist. The rest of the plane is the responsibility of the owner/flight club/flight school. As long as the plane 'looks' clean, they tend to look the other way. One winter day I had to wipe off frost of the plane by hand and that definitely cleaned the plane pretty good :)

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat There is no requirement to clean GA windows before every flight, in fact you shouldn't clean them (just verify that they are clean). Excessive cleaning causes crazing/hazing. None of the checklists on the 177 I own, nor the 172 I learned in had "clean windows" as part of the preflight checklist, it may be something your school/rental company has on their checklist.

Comment: @RonBeyer I just said that it is part of my checklist. I didn't say it was legally required or was FAA mandated or anything like that. I prefer it to be on my checklist, because when I was starting I noticed that I was sitting inside with my headset on..ready to go and couldn't see a thing outside ( mostly due to frost/dew) on the windows/windscreen.

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat you said "you are supposed to clean the windows before every flight. This is part of the checklist". That's very different from saying it's something *you* do before every flight and is a part of *your* checklist, and sounds very much like you're saying it's a legal/FAA requirement or standard manufacturer recommendation.

Comment: How confusing -  I find myself agreeing with my namesake

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I clean them whenever they are dirty to the point of affecting ability to see traffic or cause distractions.

Bugs, dust, and dirt can make it very difficult to spot traffic, birds, and obstructions, especially in hazy weather.

It is the pilot’s responsibility to “see and avoid” and clean windows play a large role in this critical safety area.

Depending on how bad contaminants are (i.e., if it’s bug season) the interval for cleaning could be as often as every flight or as little as once every few days while continuous flight operations are in effect.

Windows are cleaned with either water or special chemicals for cleaning plexiglass with microfiber or non-abrasive cloths. Also of note, human fingerprints are ideal for cleaning aircraft windows with water as they are soft and do not scratch, but the ridges pick up the dirt and easily rub off even sticky contaminants [bugs]. Aircraft windows are relatively soft and scratch very easily. All cleaning motions are done in the direction of the airflow to prevent hazing of the window from scratches... no circular scrubbing - only in the direction of air flow. Passenger windows rarely get dirty. It’s the ones for the cockpit that are directly exposed to the frontal airflow that get the worst of it.

I usually use water, my fingerprints for scrubbing, and clean microfiber cloths for drying to prevent water spots - which can obscure vision as bad as dirt.

[Here](https://youtu.be/6W8WxQA3gvg) is a video of the process.

Comment: I strongly second the water/hand method for initial cleaning of plexi.  Any windshield will have some coating of "dust" which is actually mostly silica particles along with pollen. If you just take a cloth with Mirror Glaze or some other product without a water/hand rinse first, you are literally sanding the plexi.  A great product for cleaning and polishing after the initial water cleaning is Lemon Pledge.  The lemon helps break down bugs and it doesn't streak.

Comment: I think you meant fingertips, unless you keep a baggie filled with fingerprints and sprinkle them on the window along with the water. :-)

Comment: @grumpy1arrival lol, yes I did - but it doesn’t get the point across as to why fingertips are better than a scrub brush as well as saying fingerprints does :-)

Comment: Can anyone find a video of the cleaning process?

Comment: @Pugz this copilot seems to be cleaning in a circular motion: https://youtu.be/sNGHFEaMWuI

Comment: @TayE looks like nobody ever taught him how to clean an airplane windshield :-) sadly, it exists at all levels.

Comment: @TayE I’m just being a pain. Modern jet airliner windows are made up of layers of glass, plastics, and laminates, as well as often several conductive electrical layers. This is very different from a traditional aircraft window made of just plexiglass... they must withstand the temperature of the de-icing system and also bird impacts at hundreds of knots. Either way, good practice is good practice... airflow and particles in the air always flow in the direction of airflow and it’s good not to clean against the grain.

Answer (score 7):

Although this is a small subset of aviation, at the seaplane base I worked at, windows were cleaned every morning and potentially multiple times a day if salty spray got on them. It’s the pilot’s discretion, but most pilots I know prefer a clean windscreen.