# Why are British Airways wings so dirty?

Tags: airliner, airline-operations, aircraft-maintenance, boeing-777

I often fly through Heathrow, and British Airways airplanes, particularly their 777s, always look so dirty. For example, there is often a kind of dark oily stain on the wings and flight surface. So - why are BA planes so dirty compared to the others? And what exactly is this dirty anyway?

[image]

(image from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2adzLBsSv0))

Comment: Related: [Do airlines ever clean their planes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25881/do-airlines-ever-clean-their-planes)

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is a significant issue on BA aircraft only? Or is it a 777 issue? Or a BA 777 only issue? One image from one video seems to lead to an unsubstantiated claim of "always". Maybe next time you're through LHR, take a pic of every plane parked at every gate you can get to and do a count to see if BA is really the dirtiest airline. As it stands, this seems to be unsubstantiated speculation...

Comment: @FreeMan I fly through Heathrow at least eight times a year, and have been doing so for the past 20 years. As I have said in the post, I observe dirt on BA planes, particularly on their 777 fleet, that stand out compared to other airlines. I attached an image that is a representative sample of my observations. If you choose not to believe me, that is fine - I am simply looking for a plausible explanation.

Comment: It's probably because they want them to match the dirty interior. BA is not known for the quality of their housekeeping, and I have flown them in the US, the EU, the Middle East and Africa.

Comment: @JuanJimenez It's a shame that a flag carrier, of a country known for its aviation heritage, should present itself in such an unappealing way :(

Comment: To match their 'tricks'  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Tricks_(scandal)